# In what file are the position of ui widgets in firefox saved?

Tags: firefox

I'm trying to change the position of the homepage button, but don't have the luxury of being able to do it via the GUI.

I was trying to find the file (probably a .xul file?) where the positions of those buttons etc is saved, but I couldn't find anything. Every link pointed me to the sdk, or an extension development tutorial.

Is there such a file, or another way to modify the positions, without using the GUI?

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that the file those GUI changes are saved in, is (as of FF 33) localstore.rdf.
Although modifying it by hand did not have the desired effect for me.

I did discover, however, that if you change the GUI, a new configuration entry called `browser.uiCustomization.state` gets created. It is a json string, describing the different locations and the items therein. By modifying that entry you can persistently change the positions of your widgets.

If you find yourself in the situation, that you don't have access to the `about:config` menu, you can set and modify that entry in the `pref.js` file in your profile directory ( `~/.mozilla/firefox/yourprofile/` on linux ).

My guess is, that this string will be saved in the file `xulstore.json` starting with FF34 [1], but I don't have access to that version, so someone else would need to verify.

[1] https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=559505